# Transform a Running Total in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to add a new measure which is represented by the following formula:

```
5-1.2*45/sqrt(n)
```

Where n is a running total of 1 to n, so if n were 5 I would apply this to each value of 1 through 5 and I would end up with a smooth line I can plot.

I was able to create a running total of n, which is my case is 1 to 150, and I wrapped it in the `SQRT` function, but as soon as I try and do the `-5` for example the output is no longer a running total, or at least the line which I graph is no longer smooth, it seems to convert it to a single value

Here is what I have for the running total:

```
CALCULATE (
SUM('public summary_orders_by_event'[bet_count]),
FILTER (
ALLSELECTED('public summary_orders_by_event'),
'public summary_orders_by_event'[placed_date] <= MAX( ('public summary_orders_by_event'[placed_date]))))
```

Here I tried to add the forumula to the beginning but without success:

```
5-1.2*45/sqrt(CALCULATE (
SUM('public summary_orders_by_event'[bet_count]),
FILTER (
ALLSELECTED('public summary_orders_by_event'),
'public summary_orders_by_event'[placed_date] <= MAX( ('public summary_orders_by_event'[placed_date])))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
MyMeasure =
VAR runtot =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'public summary_orders_by_event'[bet_count] ),
        FILTER (
            ALLSELECTED ( 'public summary_orders_by_event' ),
            'public summary_orders_by_event'[placed_date]
                <= MAX ( ( 'public summary_orders_by_event'[placed_date] ) )
        )
    )
RETURN
    5 - DIVIDE ( 1.2 * 45, SQRT ( runtot ) )
```

[image]